# STM32F407VE erase sector issues

Tags: erase, stm32f4, flash-memory, sector

Never mind ...

I shot myself in the foot.  I didn't select all the options properly and the program ended up erasing part of itself.

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

I'm doing a bare metal bootloader and am having some strange results when erasing FLASH sectors. I've found a work around but I'd like to know the root cause.

I started with this loop:

```
#define APP_first_sector 2
#define LAST_SECTOR 7
HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
for (uint32_t i =  APP_first_sector; i <= LAST_SECTOR; i++) {
  FLASH_Erase_Sector(i, VOLTAGE_RANGE_3);
}
HAL_FLASH_Lock();
```

The result was sometimes it worked but took minutes to complete and sometimes it would erase the first two or three sectors (sectors 2, 3 & 4) and then get lost.

Adding a print statement to the loop seemed to solved both issues.

```
#define APP_first_sector 2
#define LAST_SECTOR 7
HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
for (uint32_t i =  APP_first_sector; i <= LAST_SECTOR; i++) {
  print("Erasing sector: %d\n",(uint16_t)i);
  FLASH_Erase_Sector(i, VOLTAGE_RANGE_3);
}
HAL_FLASH_Lock();
```

A couple of days ago I came back to the project, made some changes in another area, and found that it now would erase sectors 2,3 & 4 and then hang.  Backing out the changes didn't fix the problem.

The hang turned out to be in the sprintf function.  It was processing the va_args list but never finding the end.

I was able to get around this by adding a '\0' to all print statements executed after the erase sector command.  This explicitly adds the terminating code to the va_args list but gives compile warnings.

```
print("Erasing sector: %d\n\0",(uint16_t)i);
```

The only active interrupt in the system is Systick.  All exception and isr vectors are populated.  Only reset and hard fault have unique handlers. All others just return.

I've tried adding delays to the loop, moving the LOCK/UNLOCK into the loop, putting the print after the erase command, adding "while busy" loops but nothing affected the behavior.

Came to find out that all FLASH accesses are suspended when a sector erase is in progress.  Since this is executing out of FLASH, the program halts.  I assume that the timers/clocks still keep going.

Comment: Don't know if this is of any relevance ... once into the failing mode the only way out of it is to use Ozone to download the image to FLASH.  When in the failing mode, a reset via the hardware reset button and one via Ozone's RESET AND RUN command results in normal code execution until you get to the first print where it then goes into the "scan var_args list forever" mode.

Comment: I thought maybe the image in FLASH image was getting corrupted so I dumped a freshly downloaded image to a file and then an image when in the failing mode.  The images were identical.  Now I'm wondering if there is a register setting that I'm not initializing during the init phase that's getting clobbered by the sector erase command.

Comment: Erasing sector 4 is the only one that causes problems.  It's the only 64K sector.  0-3 are 16K and 5-7 are 128k.

Comment: I've also unsucessfully tried to disable/flush all the advanced FLASH features before the erase and then flush/restore them after.

Answer (score 0):

Unintentional self-modifying code is not good!